# Start background task after receiving push in Suspended mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, push-notification

It may seem that this question was asked several times, but I'm facing a weird problem.

I have server configured to send push notification with  `content-available = 1` flag. 
I have configured my app to work in background `Background Modes` on for `Location Update`, `Background fetch` and `Remote Notifications`.
Also I have implemented all necessary code to receive push notifications in background and to start background task.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bg_task = background_task;
    background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^ {
        //Clean up code. Tell the system that we are done.
        [application endBackgroundTask: bg_task];
        bg_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
    //### background task starts
    [self updateLocationToServer];
    //#### background task ends
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}

- (void)updateLocationToServer{

[locationManager updateLocationWithCompletionHandler:^(CLLocation *location, NSError *error, BOOL locationServicesDisabled) {
    if (error)
    {
        //  Handle error here
        if (locationServicesDisabled) {
            //  Location services are disabled, you can ask the user to enable them for example
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //  Do whatever you want with the current user's location
        NSString *deviceID = [userDefs objectForKey:@"deviceID"];
        isConnected = [[userDefs objectForKey:@"connected"] boolValue];
        if (isConnected) {
            if (deviceID) {
                [self sendLocation:deviceID];
            }
        }

        localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotif.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1];
        localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        localNotif.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lat: %@ Long:%@",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location.coordinate.latitude],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location.coordinate.longitude]];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];

        NSLog(@"Lat: %@ Long:%@",[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location.coordinate.latitude],[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location.coordinate.longitude]);

        //Clean up code. Tell the system that we are done.
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask: background_task];
        background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;}}];}
```

**EDIT: Added code where I end background task. background_task variable is global.** 
The app receives push in background normally until it goes to suspended mode. The problem is that, after background task ends, and the app goes to suspended mode it does not run the code again when it receives push notification but `didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler:` does not get called. But when I open the app and exit with home button it will work again within "that" 3 minutes until it goes to suspended mode.

Comment: Do you call `endBackgroundTask` before you call the completionHandler?

Comment: Yes it gets called in `[self updateLocationToServer];` at the end when location is received. Everything works fine but only before app goes to suspended mode.

Comment: Not launching after 3 minutes indicates that perhaps you didn't end the background task cleanly - if you don't do that then iOS won't give you any more background time.

Comment: How do you pass the bg_task identifier to `endBackgroundTask`?  It is a local variable

Comment: @Paulw11 I added the code where I end background task. `sendLocation:deviceID` is synchronous task.

Comment: Your assignment between `background_task` and `bg_task` seems wrong.  `background_task` is changed after you have assigned it to `bg_task`, so in the event that your task does expire your expiration handler won't end the correct task - I don't know if this is your issue though because your normal task end code looks right

Comment: I found where the problem is. Yes you were right. The problem is in improper end of background_task, but I tried your suggestion it did not help. I changed my code not to update location after receiving remote push notification but show only local ones and ended background_task right after it, it worked perfectly. I think that problem comes when i try to end background_task in completion handler of location manager.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to solve it :D

Comment: Are you using this https://github.com/FuerteInternational/FTLocationManager ? If so, have you modified it to request always authorisation rather than when in use?  The code in GitHub Los doesn't seem to start the error timeout. Starting and stopping location services like that may not give you a very accurate position. Also, they are using a deprecated delegate method to get the location - this will work but it doesn't instill me with confidence that the author understands core location.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67388/discussion-between-paulw11-and-garnik).